# a verb for when you go through a camera footage

Tags: word-request

> The police said the CCTV cameras will be [verb here] to identify the murderer.

I'm looking for the formal (or even technical) way of saying *review*, *inspect* or *go through* the camera footage.

Answer (score 1):

Both possibilities you are thinking about are appropriate

> The police said the CCTV cameras will be **reviewed** to identify the murderer.
>   The police said the CCTV cameras will be **inspected** to identify the murderer.

other possibilities would not work

> The police said the CCTV cameras will be **interrogated** to identify the murderer.
>   The police said the CCTV cameras will be **observed** to identify the murderer.

since you can not *ask a question of camera footage (interrogate)* and *observe* is too passive.

Comment: Thanks @peter, Is this also true of calls and flight recorders?

Comment: For calls, one can simply say "We will **listen** to the calls.", "We will **review** the calls." For flight recorders, "We will **evaluate** the flight recorders.", "We will **playback** the flight recorders.". But ***"review"*** could also be used in either situation.

Answer (score 1):

As Peter already said, ***reviewed*** and ***inspected*** both work fine. Your third option (***go through***) would also work.

A host of other words could be used, too, such as: ***scanned, examined, analyzed,*** or ***studied**.*

Some words might imply the footage will be reviewed more carefully than others. For example, the word ***scrutinized*** implies a very thorough and methodical examination of the recording.